# ASP.Net Custom Server Control Not Firing Custom Event

Tags: c#, event-handling, custom-server-controls

I have created a custom server control.  It looks great and the rendered HTML is also as it should be.  I initially had it extending the ControlContainer and now it extends the WebControl (both behave the same.)  It has two properties, ImageUrl and Text.  Essentially it will render a generic HTML  tag with an  and  tags within it.

My problem is that the ServerClick event that is exposed (by NamingContainer I beleive) doesn't seem to fire.  If I add any of the ASP buttons (Link, Image or regular) and associate to that Click event it fires but of course I have extra rendered content.  It successfully runs the javascript and does the __dopostback call.  But it must not see the given control ID or something because the event never gets fired.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PLSO.Info.Web.UI {

[DefaultEvent("Submit")]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ComboButton runat=\"server\"> </{0}:ComboButton>")]
public class ComboButton : WebControl {

    private HtmlImage imageControl;
    private HtmlGenericControl spanControl;

    private static readonly object EventSubmitKey = new object();

    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Description("The text to display on the button.")]
    public string Text {
        get { return ViewState["NewText"] as string; }
        set { ViewState["NewText"] = value; }
    }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [UrlProperty()]
    [Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.ImageUrlEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string ImageUrl {
        get {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return this.imageControl.Src;
        }
        set {
            EnsureChildControls();
            this.imageControl.Src = value;
        }
    } // ImageUrl - Property

    public override string CssClass {
        get { return ViewState["CssClass"] as string; }
        set { ViewState["CssClass"] = value; }
    }

    [Category("Action")]
    [Description("Raised when the user clicks the button.")]
    public event EventHandler Submit {
        add { Events.AddHandler(EventSubmitKey, value); }
        remove { Events.RemoveHandler(EventSubmitKey, value); }
    }

    protected virtual void OnSubmit(EventArgs e) {
        EventHandler SubmitHandler = (EventHandler)Events[EventSubmitKey];

        if (SubmitHandler != null)
            SubmitHandler(this, e);
    }

    void ComboButton_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OnSubmit(EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {
        Controls.Clear();

        imageControl = new HtmlImage();
        imageControl.Src = this.ImageUrl;
        imageControl.Alt = this.Text;
        this.Controls.Add(imageControl);

        spanControl = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        spanControl.InnerText = this.Text;
        this.Controls.Add(spanControl);

        this.Submit += new EventHandler(ComboButton_Submit);

        ChildControlsCreated = true;
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        PostBackOptions pbo = new PostBackOptions(this);

        AddAttributesToRender(writer);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, this.CssClass);
        writer.AddAttribute("onclick", string.Format("javascript:{0}", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(pbo)));
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button);
        imageControl.RenderControl(writer);
        spanControl.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
    }
}
```

Here is my markup.  I put in this control and then a regular ASP:Button.  That regular button's event gets hit!  Not mine.

```
<ucs:ComboButton ID="btnT4" runat="server" Text="Please" CssClass="PButtonCombo" ImageUrl="~/Styles/icons/edit-find.png" OnSubmit="btnT4_Submit" />
<asp:Button ID="btnT5" runat="server" Text="TEST" onclick="btnT5_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

And here is the rendered HTML:

```
<button id="MainContent_btnT4" class="PButtonCombo" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$btnT4&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"><img src="../Styles/icons/edit-find.png" alt="Please" /><span>Please</span></button>
<input type="button" name="ctl00$MainContent$btnT5" value="TEST" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$btnT5&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="MainContent_btnT5" />
```

I have to believe I am close but just missing something.  Been tweaking it for hours today, PLEASE HELP!

**EDIT**:

Thanks to @James answer, all I did was add the following to the top of the above example.  It did the trick but now fires twice.  Not sure why?  So that is my current question:

```
public class ComboButton : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler {

    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) {
        OnClick(new EventArgs());
    }

    [Category("Action")]
    [Description("Raised when the user clicks the button.")]
    public event EventHandler Click;

    protected virtual void OnClick(EventArgs e) {
        if (Click != null)
            Click(this, e);
    }
```

**EDIT 2 == SOLUTION**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace PLSO.Info.Web.UI {

[DefaultEvent("Submit")]
[DefaultProperty("Text")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:ComboButton runat=\"server\"> </{0}:ComboButton>")]
public class ComboButton : Button {

    private HtmlImage imageControl;
    private HtmlGenericControl spanControl;

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [UrlProperty()]
    [Editor("System.Web.UI.Design.ImageUrlEditor, System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
    public string ImageUrl {
        get {
            EnsureChildControls();
            return this.imageControl.Src;
        }
        set {
            EnsureChildControls();
            this.imageControl.Src = value;
        }
    } // ImageUrl - Property

    protected override void CreateChildControls() {
        Controls.Clear();

        imageControl = new HtmlImage();
        imageControl.Src = this.ImageUrl;
        imageControl.Alt = this.Text;
        this.Controls.Add(imageControl);

        spanControl = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
        spanControl.InnerText = this.Text;
        this.Controls.Add(spanControl);

        ChildControlsCreated = true;
    } // CreateChildControls - Method - Override

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        PostBackOptions pbo = new PostBackOptions(this);

        AddAttributesToRender(writer);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button);
        imageControl.RenderControl(writer);
        spanControl.RenderControl(writer);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    } // Render - Event - Override
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try implementing the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface:

```
public class ComboButton : WebControl, IPostBackEventHandler  
{
    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        OnSubmit(EventArgs.Empty); 
    }
}
```

Here's an article that explains the implementation of the `IPostBackEventHandler` interface:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackeventhandler.aspx

**EDIT**

If your events are in some way dependent on data, you need to implement the `IPostBackDataHandler` interface. For example, you would use the `IPostBackDataHandler` interface to fire the `OnTextChanged` event of a TextBox:

```
public class ComboButton : WebControl, IPostBackDataHandler  
{
    public virtual bool LoadPostData(string postDataKey, NameValueCollection postCollection)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public virtual void RaisePostDataChangedEvent()
    {

    }
}
```

Here's an article that explains the implementation of the `IPostBackDataHandler` interface:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx

Comment: Sorry, I meant `IPostBackEventHandler`

Comment: That did it (MOSTLY) - Now the event fires twice.  See my answer below so I can post code.

Comment: You probably just need to rework your event handler logic a little bit. What answer are you referring to?

Comment: I tried to put the code in these comments but it treats it like a paragraph and thus is painfull to read.  So I figured if I could answer it (since I do not see a reply) that would help, but that was not the answer either.  So I just EDITED the initial post - see after the EDIT statement.

Comment: Try just moving the `OnSubmit(EventArgs.Empty)` to the `RaisePostBackEvent` method, and remove the `OnClick` event handler from the `CreateChildControls` method.

Comment: Just tried that and no luck.  I have also totally removed any of the OnSubmit stuff as well as in the CreateChildControls.  It still fires.  I then saw the OnSubmit along with the OnClick in the markup and hoped removing the OnSubmit (that was never firing) would take care of it thinking that perhaps they were both hitting now.  Sadly, no luck.  Damn, sometimes I hate computers.

Comment: Take this out: `writer.AddAttribute("onclick", string.Format("javascript:{0}", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(pbo)));`

Comment: I tried that earlier (and just now to verify) and it makes it so the event NEVER fires.

Comment: I think you need to strip away the event handling logic as much as possible and implement it again piece-by-piece.

Comment: If you get really fed up, you can always just change the class so it inherits from the `Button` control. That should take care of everything, and you can still add some custom properties to it.

Comment: I did finally get fed up.  Made it a Button and it works.  Ugh.  Anyway, my EDIT 2 above is the latest code that works.  Thank you SO MUCH @James.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into IPostBackEventHandler

If you dont implement this interface in your control ASP.net engine wont forward the events to your control.